# Getting started with Python on Mac OS X but having trouble with GUI

Tags: python

I am sure this is very simple but I can't find an answer anywhere. Let's say I have this simple temperature conversion program called ConversionSelector.py that looks like

```
# Helper function to print all menu items:
def displayMenu():
    print 'Temperature Conversions Menu:';
    print '(1) Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius';
    print '(2) Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit';

# Main function to display menu and invoke user-selected conversion:
def select():
    displayMenu();
    choice = input('Enter choice number: ');
    if (choice == 1):
        F2C();
    elif (choice == 2):
        C2F();
    else:
        print 'Invalid choice: ', choice;
    print 'Bye-bye.';

# Convert Fahrenheit temperature to Celsius temperature:
def F2C():
    Fahrenheit  = input('Enter degrees in Fahrenheit: ');
    Celsius     = (5.0 / 9.0) * (Fahrenheit - 32);
    print Fahrenheit, 'Fahrenheit =', Celsius, 'Celsius';

# Convert Celsius temperature to Fahrenheit temperature:
def C2F():
    Celsius     = input('Enter degrees in Celsius: ');
    Fahrenheit  = (9.0 / 5.0) * Celsius + 32;
    print Celsius, 'Celsius =', Fahrenheit, 'Fahrenheit';
```

I use a Mac but I can't get this to run. For example, if I type in the terminal
python ConversionSelector.py it doesn't do anything. (I have IDLE and Python Launcher installed).

Now when I open up Windows and type select() then it does show the menu with the choice to select from the two conversion methods. Typing the same in the Mac Python Shell gives me this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    select()
NameError: name 'select' is not defined

I know this is probably something very simple that I am not doing. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you importing the above file before typing `select()` in the shell? How are you importing it?

Comment: Well, it looks like I do not know how to import the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the bottom of your file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   select()
```

This will make `python ConversionSelector.py` run your select function. What's happening here is that [__name__](http://www.ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/module-name.html) is `__main__` when invoking your script directly, so you need to tell the interpreter to run your main function.

Alternatively, you could import your module from the interpreter. Run `python` in the same directory as your `ConversionSelector.py` file. Then run:

```
import ConversionSelector
ConversionSelector.select()
```

You could also run python with the `-i` option. Running `python -i ConversionSelector.py` would import your module and insert all of its names in the global namespace, so you could just run `select()`.

Comment: ok great! this worked but for learning purposes I would like to know other ways to run programs. Any other options?

Comment: Added some extra information. Not sure exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
$ python ConversionSelector.py
```

Python only runs the file. Since the function definitions are the only code in the file, nothing visible happens. If you want to load the file and then enter interactive mode, you need the -i flag:

```
$ python -i ConversionSelector.py
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's not supposed to do anything. You are just defining functions. You are not calling (thus running) them. You can add main program logic at the bottom of the file. It's a good practice to check if the module is being run as a main program (*python ConversionSelector.py*) or imported:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # main logic goes here
```

The code instead of the comment won't get extecuted if it's imported to some other file or to the interactive shell. If you want to "play" in the shell just run it (the shell, using *python* command) in the directory where file is stored and type *import ConversionSelector*. That should import the module and all the functions you defined. You can call them as ConversionSelector.function_name(). I recommend reading/watching this:

http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/introduction.html